# polynomial algorithm for Permutation in matrix

Tags: algorithm

(can't make the sigma sign look good on the browser).

For an integer n, we will mark F_n as the group of the Injective functions

`f:{1,2,3…,n}→{1,2,3…,n}`

For a given matrix A from order nXn with non-negative values we will mark:

```
P(A)=∑_(f∈F_n)▒〖A_(1,f(1))*A_(2,f(2)) 〗…*A_(1,f(1) )*A_(n,f(n))
```

Plan a polynomial algorithm that determines if  P(A)=0.
I was thinking to look for `n^2-n+1` zeros in the matrix and then in any Permutation there will be zero in the product and then the sum will be zero, that’s gives run time of O(n^2). not sure about the solution.
any thoughts? 
thanks

[image: the question]

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Are you talking about the permanent of a matrix? If so the second last term in the product should be A(n-1,f(n-1)) not A(1,f(1))

Comment: it's not really permanent it's kind of, it's have all the possibilities, all the possible permutations to chose value from each row and and multiply it and do the same for all the other permutations and sum it and check if it's zero.

Comment: I added an example for the question

Comment: What the actual is `▒`?

Comment: As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the complement of "Is there a way to place N rooks on a NxN chessboard, so that they can't attack each other, while avoiding the marked (zero) squares.

For example if one row or one column is all zeros then it is impossible and P(A) = 0,  so looking for n^2 - n + 1 zeros doesn't cut it.

There is answer over here, however, that gives a lovely polynomial-time solution to this problem: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28413/how-hard-is-this-constrained-n-rooks-problem

Comment: If there is have n^2-n zeros in the matrix it's mean we have one of two situations, all the n rows have n-1 zeros or there is at least one row with n zeros. for the first case that we don't have a row with all zeros, let's look at the permutation that choose all the non zeros values in the matrix and the and the product of this values will be greater than zero so P(A) will be greater than zero. if we have n^2-n+1, its mean there must be at least one row with all zeros so for no matter what permutation all the products will have one zero so the sum will be zero

Comment: If the last row is all zeros, then P(A) will be zero, since every product includes an element from the last row, and yet there will only be **n** zeros, not **n^2 - n + 1**

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the 27 product combinations is simple after you've applied the distributive law at all three layers.

```
(a+b+c) * (d+e+f) * (g*h*i)
```

Thus, all you have to do is to check whether any row sum is 0.